# Pipes between more than 2 children fail - C

Tags: c, pipe, fork

How can I make functional pipes between 3 or more children?

I use this command:

`./function n` with `n` the number of children.

And the the father makes `n` pipes and `n` children.

After that the children close the pipes they will not use.

Then the father writes something in the first pipe, and the first children read it, and write it to the next pipe. The last child should write the content in the `stdout`.

When I use only 1 child it works perfect. When I try to use 2 children, the last one reads from the pipe: -1 characters and when I try to use 3 children, I got segment violation and the code doesn't work.

Hope you can help me, here is the code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void use_pipes(int i);
void write_father(void);

int (*pp)[2];
int childrens;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    childrens = atoi(argv[1]);
    int p, i, j, aux;

    printf("I'm the parent and i'm making %d childrens\n", childrens);
    pp = malloc(sizeof (*pp) * childrens);
    for (i = 0; i < childrens; i++) {

        if (pipe(pp[i]) < 0) {
            perror("Error in pipe()");
            exit(1);
        }

    }//for

    for (i = 0; i < childrens; i++) {
        printf("I'm the parent pid: %d and I'm going to make the child nº: %d\n", getpid(), i);
        p = fork();

        switch (p) {
            case -1:
                printf("We couldn't make the child nº:%d\n", i);
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                //printf("I'm nº: %d, and I start my code\n",i);

                for (aux = 0; aux < childrens; aux++) {
                    if (aux == i) {
                        //printf("I'm the children nº: %d and I'm going to close the pipe[%d] of writing\n", i,i);
                        close(pp[i][1]);
                    } else if (aux == i + 1) {
                        //printf("I'm the children nº: %d and I'm going to close the pipe[%d] of reading\n", i,aux);
                        close(pp[aux][0]);
                    } else {
                        //printf("I'm the children nº: %d and I'm going to close the pipe[%d]\n", i,aux);
                        close(pp[aux][0]);
                        close(pp[aux][1]);
                    }
                }//for

                //printf("I finished to close my unused pipes\n");
                use_pipes(i);
                exit(0);

            default:
                break;
        }//switch
    }//for of fork
    close(pp[0][0]);
    for (j = 1; j < childrens; j++) {
        close(pp[j][0]);
        close(pp[j][1]);

    }//for
    write_father();
    int status;
    for (i = 0; i < childrens; i++) {
        wait(&status);
    }

}//main

void write_father() {
    int wroten;
    char buffer[50] = "Hello World";
    int len = strlen(buffer);
    wroten = write(pp[0][1], buffer, len);
    printf("The parent wrote: %d characters\n", wroten);
}

void use_pipes(int n_children) {
    int readed;
    char buffer [50];
    readed = read(pp[n_children][0], buffer, sizeof (buffer));
    printf("Children %d readed from pipe[%d][0]: %d characters\n", n_children, n_children, readed);
    if (n_children != childrens - 1) {
        printf("Children %d write in the pipe[%d][1]: %d characters\n", n_children, n_children + 1, readed);
        write(pp[n_children + 1][1], buffer, readed);
    } else
        write(1, buffer, readed);
}
```

EDIT: I posted the code that worked for me

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Experienced programmers generally always prefer to use proper indentation because it helps to visually identify the control flow and variable scope. You are asking for help, so it makes sense to do what you can to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I tried to do my best, but when I post the code here I have to manually put 4 spaces so the web recognize it like code, and the indentation becomes crazy. I would like to know if there is a way to mark part of the text like code and that the indentation stay like when I copy it from my file.

Comment: Select your code and press the "{}" button in the editing toolbar (or as per the tooltip, press ctrl+K).

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I did already a few questions here and didn't know how to fix that, so from now on I will be doing it right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.

- `int* pp[2]` doesn't mean what you think it means.  This is an array of two pointers to `int`, but what you appear to want is a pointer to an array of two `int`.  That would be `int (*pp)[2]`.  Your segmentation fault is likely related to this.
- having corrected the type of `pp`, you next must allocate it correctly; specifically, all in one chunk.  This is the cleanest way to accomplish that (note that there is no loop involved, and that the needed size is defined in terms of the size of the pointer's target):

```
    pp = malloc(childrens * sizeof(*pp));
```

If you want the parent to create all the pipes in advance then you do need to use a loop for that.

- The parent should close unused pipe ends once each, but you have it closing them once per child forked.  Move that out of the loop.
- Although C allows it, it is poor form to allow control to reach the closing bracket of `main()`.  Use a `return` statement or call `exit()` instead.
- You assume that your I/O will not split the data, so that single `write()` and `read()` calls are sufficient.  That will probably work for you, but it is not, in fact, reliable.  You should loop your `write()`s and `read()`s to transfer the full number of bytes via multiple calls when necessary.  Use the return values of these functions to help with this.
- The preceding implies that you need to communicate between processes how many bytes to read in any one message.  You could do that with a terminator (e.g. a newline or null byte), or by first sending a (fixed-size) integer that says how many characters follow in the same message.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for answer. Now I'm a bit confused. I did that `for` (the one who makes the children) with the idea that the variable `i` was copied to the memory of children, so I can use it to recognice what children is it and use it when I read/write in the pipe (for example `pp[i][1]`). I think the father only close once the pipes with the `if(i==0)`, am I right? I'm using that `for` too so I can create all the children.

Comment: I did not suggest getting rid of the `for` loop in which you create the children.  I suggested moving the code that closes all the pipe ends the parent doesn't need outside.  The `if (i == 0)` of course conditions the `close(pp[0][0])`, but only that.  The inner loop over `j` is executed for every `i`.  Since only the parent ever exits the loop, it would be much cleaner and less susceptible to error to simply handle the parent's pipe ends outside the loop.

Comment: Yes you are right, just moving outside that part of the code, works fine :) Thank you